# Group by multiple properties (Gremlin)

Tags: database, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have the following entity
`Event (date, severity, other properties)`

I want to write a gremlin query which groups the events by date and severity and returns the result in the following format:

```
[
   {
       date: "07-04-2022",
       severity: "INFO",
       count: 4
   },
   {
       date: "07-04-2022",
       severity: "ERROR",
       count: 2
   },
   ...
]
```

I tried executing the following query, but it says it cannot serialize object of type: CollectionField to a primitive value

```
g.V().groupCount().by(values('date', 'severity').fold())
```

Comment: is there more to that error message? and by the "cosmos" tag do you mean you are using CosmosDB (which should be the "azure-cosmosdb" tag?

Comment: @stephenmallette No, this is the error message. And yes, I use CosmosDB

Comment: It appears that Cosmos is not able to group using a key that is a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [CosmosDB documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support) it appears that :

> Sorting by array properties order().by(<array property>) isn't supported.
>
> Sorting is supported only by primitive types.

I imagine, as `group` is a form of sort, that same limitation applies there as well.